# executeUpdate() from my PreparedStatement returns 1 but cell in DB not updated (but instead locked)

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement

on my Tomcat WebSocket server, I have the following query in my PreparedStatement:

```
UPDATE account SET token = '7c7420651ddaf6a9b6277daf373c7093fc6c745d7dda4c47fb59e5e77764e2a3' WHERE email = 'example@domain.com';
```

However, although the executeUpdate() returns 1, the value is not being committed in my PostgreSQL database and instead, the cell remains locked (so future updates cannot write at the same destination).

PS.
The same query from pgAdmin works fine.

Comment: The obvious explanation is you have not issued a `commit` on the transaction and it is being held open.

Comment: Ohh yes, there is indeed such a method but on the Connection object. I was looking at the PreparedStatement instead. This brings me to the next question.. should I commit also after executeQuery()?

Comment: When else would you commit?

Comment: I ask because so far I haven't been noticing this problem because my executeQuery() calls were executed correctly even without calling any commit() on the connection.